# KTOR Client does not send the full Byte Arrays. Only 76 bytes get uploaded

Tags: android, retrofit, ktor, ktor-client

I'm using Ktor Client to upload a photo to the server. But the following function only sends 76 bytes according to the log.

```
suspend fun uploadImage(token: String, byteArray: ByteArray) {

        return client.submitFormWithBinaryData {
            url(MainEndpoints.UPDATE_PROFILE_PIC)
            formData {
                header("Authorization", token)
                append("photo", byteArray, Headers.build {
                    println("Original size ${byteArray.size} bytes")
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/jpg")
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=image.jpg")
                })
            }
            onUpload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
                println("Sent $bytesSentTotal bytes from $contentLength")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the log I get. No matter the image size, it only uploads 76 bytes.

```
Original size 676755 bytes
Sent 76 bytes from 76
```

Is this has to do with client configuration? Here's mine.

```
HttpClient(CIO) {
            install(JsonFeature) {
                serializer = KotlinxSerializer(
                    kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                        prettyPrint = true
                        isLenient = true
                        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    }
                )
            }
            install(HttpTimeout) {
                requestTimeoutMillis = 15000L
            }
            install(Logging) {
                logger = object : Logger {
                    override fun log(message: String) {
                        Log.i("Logging", message)
                    }
                }
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }
            install(ResponseObserver) {
                onResponse {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked what is actually uploaded in this 76 bytes? My guess is that `append` does not accept ByteArray and thus just uploads `byteArray.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Ktor 1.6.8. Please use the latest released version of Ktor where uploading works as expected. Here is the code for Ktor 2.1.1:

Configuration:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
    install(HttpTimeout) {
        requestTimeoutMillis = 25000L
    }
    install(Logging) {
        logger = object : Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                Log.i("Logging", message)
            }
        }
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }
    install(ResponseObserver) {
        onResponse {}
    }
}
```

Upload method:

```
suspend fun uploadImage(token: String, byteArray: ByteArray) {
    client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
    url(MainEndpoints.UPDATE_PROFILE_PIC),
        formData {
            append("photo", byteArray, Headers.build {
            println("Original size ${byteArray.size} bytes")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/jpg")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=image.jpg")
        }
    )
    }) {
        header("Authorization", token)
        onUpload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
            println("Sent $bytesSentTotal bytes from $contentLength")
        }
    }
}
```